# .Net Core Dependency Injection - replace dependency within a child scope

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I'm using a default .Net Core DI (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection). I need to resolve a service replacing a particular dependency with another instance. In my case it's a db connection so it's not a first-level dependency. For now the only working solution I found is to create a new service provider from scratch but it looks like a huge overhead to me. Is there a way to inherit an existing configuration replacing a single interface implementation? `IServiceProvider` and `IServiceScopeFactory` interfaces don't have any methods to modify anything.

Comment: The built-in DI implementation doesn't have nested scopes/child containers but you can easily configure it to use another DI implementation, eg Autofac

Comment: But .Asp.Net Core itself somehow provides a particular implementation, like HttpContext, for each new scope (request) so it should be possible even with built-in DI

Comment: Yes, because those are scoped services. However, there's no opportunity here to switch out how the dependency is provided per scope. It's always the same mechanism of obtaining a new instance, defined at startup.

Comment: This screams XY problem. What is the actual issue you're trying to solve, because this probably isn't the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can hook in [Autofac](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#quick-start) and then do what you want.

Then instead of injecting an instance of `IServiceProvider` you could inject `ILifetimeScope`.

It would allow you to start a scope and replace an implementation only for that scope without touching anything else.

```cs
using (var scope = _lifetimeScope.BeginScope(builder => builder.Register(_ => new MyClassThatRequiresAConnection(myConnectionString))))
{
  // this would resolve the latest registration of the class `MyClassThatRequiresAConnection`
   var myClass = scope.Resolve<MyClassThatRequiresAConnection>();
  // more code here ...
}
```

Comment: I want to avoid adding another IoC container, specifically because I'm porting my app from .Net Framework to .Net Core and replacing another IoC (Unity) with default MS implementation

Comment: It's not possible without a third party container. MS service provider is very much high level. Everything that goes deeper needs a 3rd party and Autofac is that choice you want to make

Comment: But .Asp.Net Core itself somehow provides a particular implementation, like HttpContext, for each new scope (request) so it should be possible even with built-in DI

Comment: That is a different concept and the http context is mutated on each request. Thsts why you can register IHttpContextAccessor as a singleton and use it outside of controllers.